# Jenkins: jgit is generating massive buffer files

Tags: jenkins, buffer

We have a Jenkins deployment consisting of a master and a slave both running on RH6.

Large buffer files (more than 47G) are being generated on the Jenkins slave. The files are owned by a Jenkins user account. The pattern of the file name is: `jgit_xxxxxxxxxxxx.buf`

What would be the cause of such a behavior?

Jenkins version 2.7.1